# python xml library with similar functionality to json library

Tags: python, xml, json

Python has a json library where you can do `json.loads(s)` to load json into a python data structure consisting of lists and maps. Is there something equivalent for xml? All the xml libraries I've seen map to a DOM where you have to know special API functions, which is IMO less easy to work with.

Comment: That would require XML to have a reasonable mapping into Python core types. It doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, on the simple note that JSON objects directly translate to Python objects. How do you turn XML into Python - the answer is the DOM.

There are, however, simpler ways to work with XML. The best, in my opinion, for ease of use, is [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), which allows you to iterate through the elements of the XML and create a tree, which is pretty easy to work with comparable with other ways of getting at XML data.

Comment: I'd generally agree with this, but note that lxml.etree (see http://lxml.de/) is well worthwhile -- having true XPath support, XSLT, and many other goodies while retaining etree's ease-of-use.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Indeed, if you need that functionality, `lxml` is a great library - for simpler uses, I generally find the standard library suffices.

Comment: I ended up using xml.etree.ElementTree. Thanks.